# macOS: How to determine what interrupted screensaver

Tags: sleep-wake, screensaver

I run macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013).

**TL;DR**: How can I find out what interrupted the screen saver?

I'm investigating an issue where the screensaver (which starts after 2 minutes of inactivity) gets interrupted automatically without user interaction. The Mac just sits there, with the screensaver playing, until the screensaver stops and it shows the desktop again.

Some more details:

- It happens both when connected to the charger and when on battery power.
- It happens after hours or days of use, and also right after a restart (or shut-down/start cycle).
- It happens with no apps running.
- It happens with WiFi and Bluetooth on or off (so, without any bluetooth peripheral or connection).
- It happens even if I disable handoff with iOS (I tried this after googling and reading that this could be a cause).
- All the "Sharing" options in System Preferences are disabled.
- I have never installed any apps that artificially keep the Mac awake (e.g. Caffeine).
- In Activity Monitor, if I check which processes are "preventing sleep", most of the time there is only one entry: `hidd` (Human Interface Device Daemon, that is, me interacting with mouse or keyboard), which is normal while I'm using the Mac. Sometimes, however, I can also see `sharingd` and `useractivityd`, although they disappear when I disable WiFi and/or Bluetooth, which makes me think that they're not the culprits.
- The output of `pmset -g assertions` doesn't reveal anything interesting, as I can associate it to what I've already listed above.

So my question is: how can I find out what's interrupting the screensaver? Should I check the Console app? Is there a log anywhere?

Comment: If it is reliable reproducible, logging by console is a good way to troubleshoot

Comment: Thanks @ankii, that's what I figured. It can be reproduced reliably. What should I look for in the console? How do I add the required logging?

Comment: I think you can just leave the app open